# Compilation from High-level language to low level language

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation

Isn't compilation the change of HLL to machine code or low-level language? If yes, then why is TypeScript (HLL) compiled to JavaScript which is also a HLL? And not to a low-level language?

Comment: Presumably because they target platforms that uses javascript, such as the browsers or node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [its website,](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) TypeScript is a "typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript". The question is: why 'stop' at JavaScript when you could compile directly to a lower-level language?

TypeScript is *transpiled* to JavaScript, a compilation process that is a little different from what you've described (Wikipedia):

> A [t]ranscompiler or transpiler is a type of compiler that takes the source code of a program written in a programming language as its input and produces the equivalent source code in the same or a different programming language. [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)

JavaScript is the 'different programming language' from this description, and it is a very popular language: a core technology of the web, supported by all major browsers, and servers via Node.js. A TypeScript user would choose this tool because they want or need to produce JavaScript code, but also want the optional static typing features provided by TypeScript.